# Xcode Cloud Build - Unable to load contents of file

Tags: xcode, build-error, xcode-cloud, xcode14.3

I can't get Xcode Cloud past these `"Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist'"` errors. I've tried:

- pod deintegrate/install
- cleaning and restarting Xcode (14.3)
- verified that the xcfilelist paths exist on my machine
- removed input files from my run script build phase

I can create archives manually and upload them to Apple.

[image]

Comment: I guess this file path `/Target Support Files/Pods-MyApp/Pods-MyApp-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist` has to be appended with the current directory path and all. Your repo path will be`CI_WORKSPACE`

Answer (score 0):

We are getting a very similar error. However, it is flaky, if we rerun the build it works most of the time. Sometimes even from the first time.

[build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAlD9.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Environmental information:**

`Xcode15.0`

`Cocoapods` manages dependencies.

`.gitignore` is as follows:

```
*.xcworkspace
#CocoaPods
Pods
Podfile.lock
```

**What happened :**

When i first use `Xcode Cloud`, there will be an error that `xcworkspace` cannot be found. Of course it cannot be found. According to the local steps, i need `pod install` to generate `xcworkspace` after glone is down.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/writing-custom-build-scripts) I learned that I can create a script to implement `pod install`. The path and naming of the script are strict restrictions: `$(SRCROOT)/ci_scripts /ci_post_clone.sh`, the code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
brew install cocoapods
pod setup
cd ../
pod install
```

---

**<<Question 1**: After adding the script, the current path is `$(SRCROOT)/ci_scripts`

This will cause `pod install` to fail and the following error will occur.

```
Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-xxxxx/Pods-xxxxx-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist'
```

**>>Solution 1**: `cd ../` before `pod install`

---

**<<Question 2**: I used an unsupported cocoapod source

The following error occurs:

```
[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://mirrors.xxxxxx/git/CocoaPods/Specs.git`: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
```

**>>Solution 2**: Remove the source set in Podfile